# Lazy services in symfony not working

Tags: php, symfony, lazy-loading

I am trying to lazy a database service from `services.yml` but it doesn't seem to show anything on doing this:

```
$db= $this->container->get('database');
var_dump(class_implements($db));
```

I did both:

```
 composer require ocramius/proxy-manager
 composer require symfony/proxy-manager-bridge
```

and

```
services:
   database:
     class: Namespace\Database
     lazy:  true
```

It returns just an empty array. What could I be doing wrong?

P.S. I am using the components from Symfony and not the whole framework.

Comment: As I can see a "noop" proxy is generated by default (RealServiceInstantiator class). Don't know why it is so.

Comment: But I can confirm, lazy load is not working if you just follow official docs (add composer requirements and use the lazy=true attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. If you don't use the whole symfony framework, you should set proxy instantiator after installing `symfony/proxy-manager-bridge` and `ocramius/proxy-manager`, unless it will use `RealServiceInstantiator` that just creates real objects instead proxies.

```
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->setProxyInstantiator(new \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\LazyProxy\Instantiator\RuntimeInstantiator())
```

Answer (score 1):

For Symfony ver.4 you should use:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\ProxyManager\LazyProxy\Instantiator\RuntimeInstantiator;
...
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->setProxyInstantiator(new RuntimeInstantiator());
```