# How to use lazy services with dependency injection in typo3?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, typo3

Can I use lazy services in typo3 (version 11)?

I have installed the package symfony/proxy-manager-bridge with `composer require symfony/proxy-manager-bridge`. The [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/lazy_services.html) says that is enough.

When I debug the problem I find out that `ContainerBuilder::proxyInstantiator` is null and `ContainerBuilder::setProxyInstantiator()` is never called. I think it is the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46556796/272357).

Is there a way to call `ContainerBuilder::setProxyInstantiator()` in typo3?

**UPDATE**

I was able to call `ContainerBuilder::setProxyInstantiator()` in the typo3 context with a Service.php file. But it did not help with the lazy services.

```
// myext/Configuration/Services.php
// ...
return static function (ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder) {
    $containerBuilder->setProxyInstantiator(new MyRuntimeInstantiator());
};
```

Comment: Please try to explain why you need lazy services in particular.

Comment: @Mathias Brodala Some special actions of a controller needs some special services. If we do not call the special actions we do not need to initialize the special services. So we want to check if there are performance benefits. Do you have experience with that?

Comment: Yes: usually it doesn't matter and performance issues lie somewhere completely else. In case you haven't done so yet try to run do a profiling run to see where performance bottlenecks occur. I wouldn't expect service instantiation to be the main issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TYPO3 does not support this integration for lazy services out of the box like Symfony does. Especially you cannot use Symfony bundles since these are integrations specifically meant for Symfony apps similar to extensions in TYPO3.

Within Symfony the [`Kernel::getContainerBuilder()` method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/47c2da7ab844e5b72784682bb58a2614237e82fb/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L686-L688) is responsible for injecting the proxy instantiator. Here you can see how the Symfony-specific bundle is integrated in case it exists / is installed.

So you may need to try if you can achieve something similar with a `Configuration/Services.php` which receives the `ContainerBuilder` instance as argument. See the [`Services.php` of EXT:core](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/70922420ea64266047a324af17fff8f57fb5fad8/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/Services.php) for an example.

If it works well, you can even consider publishing this as TYPO3 extension package so that others can get this up and running with a simple package installation just like in Symfony.

Comment: I accept the answer that "lazy services" are not supported by typo3